# Excel VBA Export chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, export

I know absolutely nothing about VBA, I'm just trying to have 4 charts (that are already separated in their own tabs) be seamlessly exported as PNG files to a prespecified location every time I save an excel document.

Going through some of stackoverflow's database I managed to do something similar with a worksheet that I wanted to export as a CSV, but I can't manage to do the same for my charts.

Right now thats what my VBA looks like for ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV Monthly Update").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="CSV Monthly Update.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

'This above part works well'

'The one below doesn't, I'm trying to get the chart from Worksheet "Growth_of_10k" to be exported but it gives me a Runtime error 9 about runscript being out of page'

```
Sub ExportChart()
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim myChart As Chart

    Set objChrt = Sheets("Growth_of_10k").ChartObjects(3)
    Set myChart = objChrt.Chart

    myFileName = "myChart.png"

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
    On Error GoTo 0

    myChart.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"

    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

Any idea how I would need to change the code so that the chart is exported automatically to the same location as the file (or another pre-specified location, it doesn't matter) at the same time as I save the excel document?

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question, this is really my very first endeavor with VBA and googling can only get you so far when you don't understand what you're doing.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Your code works for me - the only thing I can suggest is maybe there's a different workbook active when you run it (so it will look for the sheet "Growth_of_10k" in that workbook and not find it) Fix: `Set objChrt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Growth_of_10k").ChartObjects(3)`

Comment: It is telling me Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error. I took the Set objChrt = Sheets("Growth_of_10k").ChartObjects(3) from someone else. So I don't know what is the Chart name or number of the chart in the page I have made. I have a page called "Growth_of_10k" with only a chart in it and so on. But I don't know whats the number of the chart inside the worksheet nor do I know how to refer to those charts that I want to export.

Dropbox link:https://www.dropbox.com/s/ir3f7223nb9o2db/Avanguard%20Test%20Hypothetical%20Fund%20Cummulative%20Returns.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

A chart sheet is different from a chartobject embedded on a worksheet.

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Chart1").Export _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"
```